# chromium api c# doesent play local videos

Tags: c#, winforms, html5-video, chromium

I have made a chromium based win form browser, and it works fine! i can watch youtube videos in it, browse face book, but i can not get the video tag working at all! it works if its on public websites, but not localy...

The html file containing the  tag works fine in chrome, just not on my chromium based browser... any ideas???

I have tried open source video players like after glow and video.js, and they dont work either...

here is my html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  <style> html,body
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;

    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
        <video autoplay="true" width="1920" height="1080" src="G:\StuffUsuallyOnTheCDrive\Videos\2018-05-18 09-35-57.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

i mean, it works in chrome so i expect it to work in my broweser... but it doesent.

Comment: does your build have developer tools, and if so any errors in console or network tab? can you open your g:\stuff... file from the address bar? also just as an FYI `autoplay` is a binary flag (present==true, absent==false) so you don't need the ="true")

Comment: it does not have developer tools sadly, i can open the file  (tested with a simple p tag) and thanx for the aditional info! I opened the file in chrome (which worked) and checked for any errors in the console and network tab and there is none... which just makes the whole situation harder to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

- For **local files** you need to use the `file://` protocol (versus the `http://` protocol for online files).
- If there is spaces in the URL (path) then you must signal that space with a `%20` code.
  *Example*: `my video file.mp4` becomes this path in web environment `my%20video%20file.mp4`.
   Fix your video filename path `2018-05-18 09-35-57.mp4`. It has a space...

Try:

```
<body>
    <video autoplay="true" width="1920" height="1080" src="file:///G:/StuffUsuallyOnTheCDrive/Videos/2018-05-18%2009-35-57.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</body>
```

Comment: That sadly hasent worked either... how ever it absolutly should! Could it be a bug within the chromium api? or is it my implementation of it? the strange part is, it plays video from the video tag on live webpages!  thank you for the help tho!

Comment: PS: The html and the video must both be local. You cannot mix local-and-online.